# Fetching documents based of multiply values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My documents have categories. it can be both a single or many ("category 1, category 2,..)

I have been trying to use regular expressions in order to fetch using the following code, so far with no luck:

```
  const categoriesStr = category.replace(",", "|");
  params.category = `\\${categoriesStr}\\`;
```

Comment: Wrong slash?  Or perhaps use [$regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#-regex)

Comment: yep, that's what works eventually . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to do something like this:

```js
const category = "category 1, category 2"
const categoriesStr = category.replace(/,\s*/g, "|"); // Replace all commas with "|"
const params = {};
params.category = new RegExp(`^(${categoriesStr})$`, "i"); // Create a regular expression

console.log(params.category);
```

Comment: basically yes , i just was not clear about the format . eventually i just used { "$regex" : "category A | category B } , which i guess does the same.